Accessing variable name inside proc in tcl
I am trying to create a proc that lists all elements of an array:
Here is the proc:
proc array_values {array_input} {
  upvar $array_input arr
  foreach name [lsort [array names arr]] {puts "arr($name) : $arr($name)"}
}

When I call the proc with this arguments:
array_values CMN_CLK_DIG_PATH

I get the output:
arr(0) : u_sm/u_sm_n/u_sm_ph/u_chip/Icmn0/
arr(1) : u_sm/u_sm_n/u_sm_ph/u_chip/Icmn1/

Instead, I want the output as:
CMN_CLK_DIG_PATH(0) : u_sm/u_sm_n/u_sm_ph/u_chip/Icmn0/
CMN_CLK_DIG_PATH(1) : u_sm/u_sm_n/u_sm_ph/u_chip/Icmn1/

Any idea how to do that?

The variable array_input is still valid in your proc. Its value is string "CMN_CLK_DIG_PATH". So simply replace arr with $array_input :
foreach name [lsort [array names arr]] {puts "$array_input\\($name\\) : $arr($name)"}


Instead of escaping the parentheses, we can brace the variable: puts "${array_input}($name) ...

You could also use format to assemble the strings together. That's what parray does internally.
